# how to add a glowing green line effect at the bottom of any applet or any icon

Tags: 16.10

i saw a video a guy has glowing green line effect at the bottom of his icons when he opens them there was a effects of green glowing line at the 
bottom when he opens like applet,icons,anything he have a glowing green line
could i do that in ubuntu 16.10
i have a image too [image of effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4wgC.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the person who made the screenshot is using KDE. A good start might be to use Kubuntu or install the `kubuntu-desktop` package (if you're not already using KDE).

Comment: he is actually using kali linux but could we do it in ubuntu desktop or in other desktop enviroment

Comment: I don't know the details of how it was done, but it looks like they were using KDE on Kali Linux. If you want to duplicate their setup, you would probably also want to use KDE (on Ubuntu). Is there any way you could contact the person who made the video, in order to ask about the details of their setup?

Comment: no i  don't have any details but as i know kde plasma don't look like those screenshots please help

Comment: after so much of research i got that this is called ghost theme in kali linux could we install it in ubuntu i got a link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHrRUMasgyY

Comment: After you install KDE (by installing the `kubuntu-desktop` package), you should be able to select the KDE session on Ubuntu's login screen. Then google "kde ghost theme" and download and install that specific theme for KDE.

Comment: i had tried that but no use i want ubuntu like launcher in kubuntu kde